# Как раздать разные куки разным TChromium

Tags: delphi, cookie, delphi-10-berlin, tchromium

**Имеем:** https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3 Установлено, работает.

**Требуется:** в одной проге разным `TChromium` раздать разные куки.

В официальных доках нарыл, что нужно юзать `GetCookieManager` в Event'ах экземпляра `TChromium`. Проблема в том, что в той реализации dcef3 (самая последняя по ссылке) отсутствует `GetCookieManager`. Может кому-то встречался "допиленный" компонент? Руками объявил по аналогии, но почему-то он не вызывается.
Менеджеры куки созданы и работают. Осталось только их привязать к конкретным экземплярам.

Если кто шарит по теме, то могу скинуть чуток подпиленные исходники компонента, в которых эвент уже отображается, но не выполняется.

```
procedure TformX.BrowserGetCookieManager(Sender: TObject; const browser:
  ICefBrowser; const mainUrl: ustring; out Result: ICefCookieManager);
begin
  Result := CookieManager;
end;
```

Comment: Нашел версию ещё свежее: https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3/tree/2883 Посмотрю её, может там добавлено. Пока вопрос актуален.

Comment: И ещё новее нашёл: https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3/tree/2924 Вопрос актуален.